# Set value of email address input doesn't workk

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to fill a text input of email address in [signup live](https://signup.live.com)
I got the input element and set its value to whatever I need by:
`document.getElementById("MemberName").value = "randommail232@hotmail.com"`
the input was actually filled but when I press "Next" to continue, it says "An email address is required" as the input field was empty.
How can I fix this?

P.S: after some hours of trying I guess its because there is no keyboard button press event, but I'm not sure about that and a simulation of keyboard key press isn't working for me.

Comment: Why you need that? instead of insert value you need to write letter only first part without @

Comment: Did you try sending `input` and `change` events?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try triggering `change` event manually -

```
var el = document.getElementById("MemberName");
el.value = "randommail232@hotmail.com";
el.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
```